# Передача id через строку таблицы

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Есть вот такая станица с заказами:

[image: Заказы]

При нажатии на строку с заказом открывается информация о товарах:

[image]

Как передать id заказа при нажатии на строку таблицы?

Comment: А куда передать?

Comment: @martdn id колонки может отличаться от id заказа и зачем jquery и нативный js мешать?

Comment: @Naumov я не совсем то хотел написать, случайно отправил коммент, теперь удалил )

Comment: передается в контоллер. где из базы вытаскиваются товары по айди заказа

Comment: Нужно больше информации как передаёться? чем? как пробывали?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class="table-line-for-click" data-product-id="111">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="refresh-button">Refresh</button></td>
        <td>Bla</td>
        <td>Bla</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery** & **JavaScript**

```
(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.table-line-for-click', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('refresh-button')) {
            return false;
        }
        var productId = $this.attr('data-product-id');
        alert(productId); // Это для примера в своем коде не использовать
        return false; // Это для примера в своем коде не использовать
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                productId: productId
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST'
        }).done(function(data){
            // Тут пишите обработчик ответов
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.refresh-button', function(e){
        alert('Click button'); //Тут заменить на обработчик
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})();
```

Ничего сложного и грандиозного )))

Очень важно не использовать в данном приеме тег  и у кнопок в таблице у всех использовать атрибут **type="button"** в противном случае, у Вас будет постоянно обновляться форма и результата будет 0.

Весь обмен данными должен идти при помощи AJAX запросов (методы запросов уже сами выбирайте те которые Вам больше подходят)

P.S. Я там заметил на картинке еще типа вопросик если он кликабельный, то для него нужно сделать тоже самое что и для кнопки такой же обработчик события нажатия только на вопросик. **(по классу!!! не используйте ID только class)**

Comment: Спасибо, а можно по подробней что писать в "// Тут пишите обработчик ответов"

Comment: @MykolaShkit, а без остальных данных я вам ничего тут больше не скажу и не напишу, я не знаю какой у Вас там код чтобы Вам что-то подсказать большее...

Comment: Ниже вставил код

Answer (score 0):

```
         <?php foreach($data['orders'] as $order) { ?>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer">
        <td>
            <?=$order['id_order']?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="" method="get">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$order['id_order']?>">
                <select name="status">
                    <option value="new">Новый</option>
                    <option value="treated">Обработан</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Обновить">
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$order['time']?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$order['name']?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$order['price']?>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$order['id_order']?>">
                <img src="http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/humano2/128x128/gnome-help.png" title="xfgjxfh" width="15px" height="15px">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </td>

        <?php } ?>
</div>
</table>
    <?php foreach($data['tovar'] as $tovar) { ?>
    <p><?=$tovar['article']?>  <img src="<?=$tovar['url_img']?>" width="40px" height="45px"> <?=$tovar['name']?> <?=$tovar['count']?>шт*<?=$tovar['price']?>грн</p>
    <?php } ?>
```

Это там где выводится 
А это то как выводится

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
    $this->data['tovar'] = $this->model->showTovar($id);
```

Comment: Я думаю дальше Вас стоит учить язык программирования, и разбираться то как оно там работает...